# Resizing 3D volumetric image to a specified size in python (skimage.misc.imresize is removed)

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to resize a 3D medical PET image to the same size as a CT image, and no solutions I found so far worked.
I want to resize the PET image (256,256,159) to the same size as CT image (960,960,960). These dimensions might change later however.

So far i tried:

`skimage.transform.resize(PETimg, (960,960,960), order=0)`

Which gives a memory error (and seems to make the wrong dimensions):

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.8 GiB for an array with shape (3, 960, 960, 960) and data type float64`

I also tried using PIL by wrapping in Image, and cv2, but both seems to not be compatible with 3D images.

I had luck using

`scipy.ndimage.zoom(ArrayDicomPET, (960/256, 960/256, 960/159), order=1)`

But as stated in the title, I want to simply specify my output pixel size and choose an interpolation method, just as `skimage.misc.imresize`

Does anyone know a solution for 3D images? I would prefer to not downgrade skimage.

Comment: How are you suposed to resize the last dimension? Because for width and height there are many interpolation methods, but many of them (if not all) wouldn't work for the 3rd dim, right?

Comment: The same way you generalize from 1D to 2D I think? But I might be wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grandaddy of functions like zoom and resize is [affine_transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html#scipy.ndimage.affine_transform). This can handle any combination of scale, skew, reflection, rotation, or translation. It can handle any dimensional data. It can do any interpolation method from nearest neighbor to quintic splines.